# Regex to match first three octets of IP address

Tags: regex

I see this regular expression will match an IP address:

```
\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b
```

How do I change it so it will only match the first three octets of an IP address?

So, provided with `1.2.3.4`, it will only match `1.2.3`.

Comment: If you know what your delimiters look like, then you don't need a regex, you need to `split`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, the regex you supplied is incorrect. It will match an IP adress, but also something like `192a168.1f12`. The reason is because `.` is a special character in regular expressions which equates to any character. Escape this with a `\` so you get `\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}\b` and you have an IP address regex.

Then, analyze the regex - it consists of two main parts - the part for the `a.b.c.` part where a, b and c are numbers with one to three digits (which is technically not an IP address since it should go to 255, but it's close enough) and then there's the last one to three digit number part.
Notice that the first part ends with a `{3}`, specifying it should appear 3 times. You want it to appear only 2 times, followed by the same second part so you get `\b(?:\d{1,3}\.){2}\d{1,3}\b`.

This should be enough for you, but depending on your requirements, you could also make sure that the first three octets are followed by the last octet (but not match it) by using a positive-lookahead.

Also, you don't really need a non-matching group so you can simplify your regex to this:

`\b(\d{1,3}\.){2}\d{1,3}\b`

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
address: \b(?:\d{1,3}.){2}\d{1,3}\b
```

Allright so what does the above mean? well `\d` matches a digit, the {1,3} means that there should be 1-3 digits no more, no less. the dot `.` actually matches any character (including dots, more correctly would be `\.`) Since we have this statement inside of parentheses, and here I have to confess I have no clue which language you're using, although i suspect it's PHP so I don't really know what the `?:` does. But the `{2}` after those says that the pattern will repeat twice, then the last `\d{1,3}` matches the third octet.

Comment: Thank you. One more question if you don't mind. Is there a way to match the last octet of an IP address?

Comment: Do you have some more info about how you want to match this? Is the IP at the end of a string? Do you want to extract the last octet of a full IP address? Etc.